# How to broadcast constantly changed data for custom BLE device using Core Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a hardware that constantly broadcasting kCBAdvDataManufacturerData and the advertisementData can be retrieved by function: centralManager(didDiscover peripheral:CBPeripheral).

Now I want to design an app that makes my iPhone functions as the hardware so that the iPhone can be connected to other devices and providing services. The biggest issue is to let the app broadcast manufacturer data(the data is constantly changed every second because it contains a time stamp).

The problem is CoreBluetooth filters out advertisement data, except kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs, kCBAdvDataLocalName. If I make the manufacturer data as the value of a characteristic of a service of a peripheral with certain UUIDs, how to let the value constantly changed every second?

Comment: Correct. You cannot do this on iOS. If you're in the foreground, you can put it in the local name, but there is no way to do this in the background. Centrals will need to connect to your app and you can notify them every second of new values, but you can't do this with advertising on an iPhone.

Comment: @RobNapier yeah, if I make it in the local name, the limitations are: strange bluetooth name being broadcasted and the name need to be changed every second (the other devices that try to connect the peripheral will lost target)

Comment: Yes, the local name is not particularly helpful, but it's the only thing you can put arbitrary data in. What you're trying to do is not possible on an iPhone without making connections. (I'm not sure what you mean by "will lost target" though. Devices don't connect based on local name. Many devices don't even have a local name. Devices connect using the BRADDR.)